# WP_Query diff request when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my wp_query:

```
$postagens = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => array('social', 'noticia', 'entretenimento', 'esporte', 'video', 'reporter', 'culinaria', 'cobertura', 'entrevista'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'desc'
));
```

When im logged in, this is the $postagens->request:

```
SELECT al_posts.* FROM al_posts WHERE 1=1 AND al_posts.post_type IN ('social', 'noticia', 'entretenimento', 'esporte', 'video', 'reporter', 'culinaria', 'cobertura', 'entrevista') AND (al_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR al_posts.post_author = 1 AND al_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY al_posts.post_date desc;
```

if im not logged in:

```
SELECT al_posts.* FROM al_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_type = 'social' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) OR ( al_posts.post_type = 'noticia' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) OR ( al_posts.post_type = 'entretenimento' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) OR ( al_posts.post_type = 'esporte' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) OR ( al_posts.post_type = 'video' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) OR ( al_posts.post_type = 'reporter' AND ( 1=1 AND ( ( al_posts.post_status IN ('publish') ) ) ) ) ) AND al_posts.post_type IN ('social', 'noticia', 'entretenimento', 'esporte', 'video', 'reporter', 'culinaria', 'cobertura', 'entrevista') AND (al_posts.post_status IN ('publish','private')) ORDER BY al_posts.post_date desc;
```

Is it, im waiting for ur response :D

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Here is from the wordpress codex:

post_status (string / array) - use post status. Retrieves posts by Post Status. Default value is 'publish', **but if the user is logged in, 'private' is added**. And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are 'future', 'draft' and 'pending'.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
Go down to status parameters.

If you want add.. 
    'post_status' => 'publish' 
to your array to only show the published posts in the query